# C++: How to print a multiplication table using nested loop?

Tags: c++, nested-loops, multiplication

I am running a program in c++ which prints the multiplication table from 1 to 40 but it starts from 13*10=130 to 40 so whats the reason behind this?

Comment: Can we see actual code?

Comment: I just wrote a similar program on VS2013, and tried to print it.
Guess what, it also displayed me table starting from 13*10=130 :D
But that does not mean it has not printed the previous data.
It has written it but DOS Shell can not print so many lines.
Try writing it to a file. Cheers

Comment: @Laserbreath actual code is # include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
 for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++)
 {
  for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
  {
   cout << i << " * " << j << " = " << i*j << endl;
  }
  cout << endl;
 }
 return 0;
}

Comment: @AdilIslamButt Thanks! That makes things a lot easier!

Answer (score 0):

Below is the formatted version of the code you posted:

```
#include<iostream> 

using namespace std; 

int main() { 
    for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++) { 
        for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) { 
            cout << i << " * " << j << " = " << i*j << endl; 
        } 
        cout << endl;
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

**It starts printing at 13 * 10. What's the reason for this?**

Notably, we can see the variables of both loops (`i` and `j`) are initialized to `1` when the loop starts. Because of this, you would be right in expecting the first loop-through to print `1 * 1 = 1`.

This suggests, as PRIME has pointed out, that the environment (such as the Windows Console) that you are printing to may not have a large enough buffer to store and display the 440 lines of output the program will try to print.

**How can I get around this?**

You can try re-sizing your printing environment's internal buffer (if it allows) to allow for 440 lines of print. In `MS-DOS`, for example, you can manually change this by right-clicking the title-bar, going into `Properties`, then the `Layout` tab, and changing the Screen Buffer width and height to values that suit.

Alternatively, you could conserve print-space by replacing `endl` statements with regular spaces, a la:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++) { 
    for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++)
        cout << i << " * " << j << " = " << i*j << ' '; 
}
```

You also have the option of outputting to a file instead of your current printing environment:

```
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std; 

int main() { 
    ofstream Output("Output.txt");          //Creates a file "Output.txt"
    if (Output.is_open()) {                 //If the file is open, proceeed
        for (int i = 1; i <= 40; i++) { 
            for (int j = 1; j <= 10; j++) 
                Output << i << " * " << j << " = " << i*j << '\n';  
             Output << '\n';               //^^^Write multiplication table to the file
        }
    } 
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: If Console have not  a large enough buffer to store and display the 440 lines of output then it should be started from 1*1=1 and so on till it reaches  its maximum length so whats the reason of printing from 13*10?

Comment: If the buffer isn't large enough, it'll erase the earliest outputs to create print space. 1 * 1 = 1 is *the* earliest output, so it's erased first, followed by 1 * 2 = 2, and so until, until finally 13 * 10 = 130 is shown.